# Why delete method of SCIM REST API returns status 200?

Tags: rest, sap, hana, scim, sap-business-technology-platform

I try to delete user from SAP Cloud Id with [SCIM REST API](https://help.sap.com/viewer/6d6d63354d1242d185ab4830fc04feb1/Cloud/en-US/2f215687fcf34170b0bbc8b36b60f2e9.html#loio436015d66dad4c129a87604eda2f7134).

And when I send delete request through HANA `$.net.http.Request` I get status 200 and empty response body. And user is not deleted. I tested the same request for same user with Postman and there is everything is ok, I got status 204 No Content as intended. Maybe someone faced with similar problem or has an idea how to solve this or at least get reason of such response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved this prolem. This was my mistake, I didn't know that delete request in SAP HANA is `$.net.http.DEL` and not `$.net.http.DELETE`, so it send some default request instead of throwing an error